# GGally::ggpairs behaves differently for different variables when dealing with NAs

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I have a dataset that I load with `readr` that has 2341 rows, 401 columns, and a few `NA`s peppered in. I'm trying to create scatterplot matrices with a subselection of continuous variables.

Here's a `glimpse` of some of the variables I use:

```
Observations: 2,341
Variables: 3
$ Height <dbl> 175.2000, 175.0000, 174.7000, 174.0000, 173.0000, ...
$ gender <fct> Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, ...
$ lb_pp  <dbl> 55.00000, 50.00000, 40.00000, 56.00000,  60.00000, ...
```

The variables `Height`, `lb_pp`, and `gender` have 98, 150, and 0 NAs, respectively.

Most of the variables are well-behaved and appear in the plot as normal.  `ggpairs` throws a warning when I use the variable with 150 NAs (warning message below), but I get the plot no problem as below:

```
Warning message:
“Removed 150 rows containing non-finite values (stat_boxplot).”`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
Warning message:
“Removed 150 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).”Warning message:
“Removed 150 rows containing non-finite values (stat_density).”
```

[image: Example image using variable with NA that produces expected output]

But when I use another variable `height`, it chokes big time with a different warning message and a screwed up plot:

```
Warning message:
“Removed 98 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count).
”Warning message:
“Computation failed in `stat_count()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 392, 400, 1
”Warning message:
“Computation failed in `stat_count()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 542, 574, 1
”Warning message:
“Removed 98 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count).”Warning message:
“Computation failed in `stat_count()`:
arguments imply differing number of rows: 392, 400, 1”
```

[image: Example image using variable with NA that produces unexpected output]

I am able to workaround the issue by filtering out rows that have NAs for the troublesome variables, but why do I have to do this for some vars but not others? The two variables both return `TRUE` when I ask `is.numeric`. What's the difference?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please can you make a reproducible example either with a subset of your data or some simulated data.

Comment: Probably better to post here https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, turns out my pesky variable `height` that elicited the error was not an atomic vector, but rather a `n x 1` matrix. Annoyingly, this is what R's `scale` built-in function had silently returned, in my case. A recent change in Tidyverse's `glimpse` function now shows a matrix's dimensions in the output rather than a sample of values, which is how I spotted the error.